# Consequence of Calderon-Zygmund Inequalities for the Cauchy-Riemann operator

Tags: analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the proof of the following :

> Let $\Omega$ be one of the following domains: The cylinder $\mathbb{R}\times S^1,$ the strip $\mathbb{R}\times ]0,1[$, the half-cylinder $]0,\infty[\times S^1,$ the half-strip $]0,\infty[\times ]0,1[$. For every $r>1$ there exsits a constant $Cr(\Omega)\geq 1$ such that $||\nabla v||_{L^r(\Omega)}\leq C_r(\Omega)||(\partial_s-J_0\partial_t )v||_{L^r(\Omega)}$ for every $v\in W_{0}^{1,2}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)\times W^{1,2}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

The proof says that we can start by proving $||\nabla \phi||_{L^r}\leq c(r)||\bar \partial \phi||_{L^r}$ for any $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}\times S^1)$ and $r\in ]1,\infty[$., where $\bar \partial =\partial_s+i\partial_t$. Then says that we can apply Schwarz reflection principle, we obtain an analogous estimate for $\phi \in C^{\infty}([0,\infty[\times S^1,\mathbb{C})$ with real boundary conditions and for $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}\times [0,1],\mathbb{C})$ with real boundary conditions. A second reflection yields the analogous estimate for $\phi \in C^{\infty}([0,\infty[\times [0,1],\mathbb{C})$ with real boundary conditions. And then the result follows by identifying $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $J_0$ with $-i$.

Now I am a bit lost why Schwarz reflection principle will give us the estimates and why we can idenitfy $J_0$ with $-i$, shouldn't it be $i$?

Any englightment is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. This looks interesting to understand and follow. Could you please define the derivatives $\partial_t$ and $\partial_s$. Also, by $v\in W^{1,2}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$ you mean  $v\in W^{1,2}(\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n)$.